# How do I share my Linux screen via a URL?

Tags: screencasting

My use case is really particular: I am trying to use my screen with a VR set.

I only have a google cardboard and a smartphone, but I installed GizmoVR which is a VR player and web browser screen and it's really good. If only I could live cast my screen and make it accessible from a URL I could just use GizmoVR and use the browser to display my screen in a 180° environment with head tracking.

I don't really care if I can't use the keyboard or the mouse in the app, I only need to stream my screen with a very low bandwidth, as I will stay in front of my desk I still can use my physical keyboard and mouse.

I heard about VNC but I believe this doesn't really cast the screen as-is.
I also tried to use `google-remote-desktop` program, it works well from a computer to another computer but in GizmoVR you can't connect to a google account for security reasons, which is unfortunate because I was so close to achieve what I really want.

Any advice?

Comment: Try `VNC`. Check this: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-share-your-desktop-in-linux-using-x11vnc

Comment: Thanks, that is a very good informative link. I am reading your comment in VR right now. I didn't know VNC could actually share a local screen. Also I am using a VNC VR android app at the moment, I tried noVNC in gizmoVR app but the web browser of gizmoVR is probably not that great as it failed to load some javascripts. Thanks for the link, I'll try to use `x11vnc` over `tigerVNC`.

Comment: closed my own post. reason: found my own solution

Comment: A solution to a problem is a solution, no matter who finds it. So you might want to share it with the rest of the community by using the option "answering your own question."

Comment: I think [novnc](https://novnc.com) if what you are looking for. Your question might more welcomed on the https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com . Setting up novnc correctly is not so easy, but probably you might find some prepackaged (docker?) version.